# Create New Column With Consecutive Count Of First Series Based on ID Column

Tags: r, aggregate-functions, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I work in the healthcare industry and I'm using machine learning algorithms to develop a model to predict when patients will not show up for their appointments. I'm trying to create a new feature that will be the sum of each patient's most recent consecutive no-shows.  I've looked around a lot on stackoverflow and other resources, but cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.  As an example, if a patient has no-showed her past two most recent appointments, then every row of the new feature's column with her ID will be filled in with 2's.  If she no-showed three times, but showed up for her most recent appointment, then the new column will be filled in with 0's.

I tried using plyr's ddply with cumsum, but it did not give me the results I'm looking for. I used:

```
ddply(a, .(ID), transform, ConsecutiveNoshows = cumsum(Noshow))
```

Here is an example data set ('1' signifies a no-show):

```
ID  Noshow
 1       1
 1       1
 1       0
 1       0
 1       1
 2       0
 2       1
 2       1
 3       1
 3       0
 3       1
 3       1
 3       1
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
ID  Noshow  ConsecutiveNoshows
 1       1                   2
 1       1                   2
 1       0                   2
 1       0                   2
 1       1                   2
 2       0                   0
 2       1                   0
 2       1                   0
 3       1                   1
 3       0                   1
 3       1                   1
 3       1                   1
 3       1                   1
```

I'll be very grateful for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to `sum()` for each `ID` the number of `Noshow` before a `0` appears.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ConsecutiveNoshows = sum(!cumsum(Noshow == 0) >= 1))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [13 x 3]
#Groups: ID [3]
#
#      ID Noshow ConsecutiveNoshows
#   <int>  <int>              <int>
#1      1      1                  2
#2      1      1                  2
#3      1      0                  2
#4      1      0                  2
#5      1      1                  2
#6      2      0                  0
#7      2      1                  0
#8      2      1                  0
#9      3      1                  1
#10     3      0                  1
#11     3      1                  1
#12     3      1                  1
#13     3      1                  1
```

Comment: Steven, I applied your solution to my much larger data set and it worked exactly as intended. Thank you very much for teaching me the thought process you used to find the solution.

Comment: @JamesMarquez Glad it helped :)